# Appropriate Use of Dynamic Keyword in C# with Templated Function

Tags: c#, function, templates, c#-4.0

I am new to C#.  I have read that the use of the keyword `dynamic` is somewhat controversial, and that other methods may be preferred depending on the use case.  I want to make sure that my use of `dynamic` is appropriate for the language and the case.  I'm working with this code:

```
public void myMethod(Action<T> myFunc) {
    dynamic arg = "example"; // a string
    myFunc(arg); 
}
```

I don't know what the type `T` will be until runtime, and so I thought that `dynamic` would be useful.  In the event that `T` is a string, I want to invoke `myFunc` with that argument.  Is using `dynamic` the best way to do this in C#?

edit: To give more context, if `T` is string, then I want to pass `arg` to `myFunc`.  If I don't use `dynamic`, I get an error that "cannot convert from 'string' to 'T'".  Using `dynamic` solves this problem, I'm just not sure if it's the best way to solve it.

Comment: You must have defined the generic type `<T>` somewhere. So you should already know what it is. Can you provide more context of what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: My pleasure; thanks for your patience with me as well.  When you say "I should already know what the generic type is", can you be more specific with what you mean?  There's no class or type definition for `T` as far as I can tell in this codebase.  To give more context, if `T` is string, then I want to pass arg to myFunc.  Does that make sense? @JeremyLakeman

Comment: You can only compile `Action<T>` if `<T>` is defined as a generic parameter, probably on the class. In which case the class should know what `where` constraint is defined. So `myMethod` must be able to handle all `T arg` values to pass as an argument. `dynamic` doesn't help you solve that problem. Anyway, you should expand your question to describe the actual problem you are trying to solve. Because it sounds like you've already painted yourself into a corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That is not an appropriate usage. You code will fail *at runtime* if `T` is anything other than string. That is the thing with dynamic, *it turns of compiler checks*, it does not mean your code will run, only that compiler errors turn into runtime errors. Dynamic is intended for interoperability with dynamic languages, or COM, where you are forced to cast objects at runtime anyway, so dynamic just makes it easier, without loosing any actual safety.

If you want to give `myFunc` a string, declare it as `Action<string>`. If you want to create a new object and give it to `myFunc`, add a `new()` restriction, i.e.

```
public void myMethod(Action<T> myFunc) where T : new(){
    myFunc(new T()); 
}
```

If you don't know how to construct T, let the caller give it to you:

```
public void myMethod(Action<T> myFunc, T value) {
    myFunc(value); 
}
```

You can also use `Func<T>` to give your method a delegate that constructs values on demand.

Also `Action<T>` would be called a "generic delegate". Even if c++ templates and c# generics are used for a similar purpose, they work in a very different way. In effect c# generics is more restrictive, but also makes compiling much faster and easier since you do not have to generate code for each specialization until it is jitted.